# Editing links in questions and answers

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, broken-link

I came to see a question on Stack Overflow two days ago that had a link to a tutorial on [vlcj](/questions/tagged/vlcj), but the link that the question as well as an answer used, are no longer available, but are dead. I edited the link [on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2602835) as well [as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2602828), updated it to the newer one. **But the edits weren't applied, neither to the question, nor the answer**.

Are we not allowed to edit links contained in the question or answer, even if the links are no more available and I have the new link.

I had mentioned in the details, the old link is no longer available, here is the newer one.

What if someone close to solving the problem just misses something important just due to the dead links?

**Are we not allowed to edit the links?**

Comment: Could you link to the question?

Comment: will try to @AsheeshR Let me search.

Comment: Why the bold, and `\`code\`` for something that is not code?

Comment: Added links @OptimusPrime.

Comment: Did you read the rejection reasons?

Comment: @OptimusPrime Your profile page, under the [activity tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1723626/optimus-prime?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) has a link to much of your activity on the site.  It can be very helpful for looking at your suggested edits and what edits were rejected, and why.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks. I never wnet to see why the edits were rejected, I did not even know that we could see that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, you are encouraged to edit posts to fix broken links whenever you are able to do so.

So aside from that, I don't really know what this question is about. I can *guess* that you're talking about [these](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2602828) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2602835) edits that you recently suggested and had rejected.

But like the reviewers' rejection reasons indicate, your updated link was also invalid (returns a 404). So no, you're not supposed to edit posts to replace broken links with broken links. If you can't fix a broken link, you should:

- leave a comment informing the poster and hope that they know of an alternative location for the resource, or
- edit the answer to remove the link and clean up the post so that its absence is not noticeable.

Oh yeah, and [this is why posts that contain *only* links are not acceptable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), because the links inevitably go dead and render the content useless to anyone else in the future. If you run across such a post, whether question or answer, that has a dead link, the original poster can't be reached for comment, and the post is useless without the link, you should flag it for deletion by a moderator.

Comment: Isn't fixing just one link in a post "too minor"?

Comment: oh right. I could not see why was edits rejected actually its not `.php` at the end, but `.html`. I would edit the links now. See the [new link](http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj/tutorial1.html) works.

Comment: @AsheeshR Not necessarily, no. If the link is important to the post, and it's dead, then fixing the link counts as a significant improvement over the original. But yeah, I mean, I would like to see editors fix other problems *also* while they're "in there".

Comment: No, neither of these links work either: http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/vlcj/tutorial1.html, http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/vlcj/tutorial1.htm

Comment: @CodyGray http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj/tutorial1.html

Comment: @AsheeshR IMO "too minor" does not necessarily mean small.  A good edit can be big or small.  The key is editing everything.  If the edit fixes all problems in the post, then it is substantial.

Comment: @AsheeshR IMO, the question are answer are not only to help the OP, but also those who come to stackoverflow later with their problem, would they surely get the same help if links are broken and links are good?

Comment: Links fixed now, with a couple of other minor edits thrown in for fun. Plus I upvoted that answer, even though I don't know anything about the subject, because it is *very good* and somehow has been missed by the community.

Comment: Any post should not be so dependent on links to convey information such that it doesn't make sense without them. The fact that changing the link in a post qualifies as a *substantial edit* for it shows that there are problems in it, IMO.

Comment: @AsheeshR Replacing a broken link in a post by a working one is sufficient to count as substantial. Fixing other issues is appreciated but not required. The point of rejecting “too minor” edits is to teach editors to avoid wasting time on one inconsequential spelling error or the like. The only time fixing a broken link would count as too minor is if the post should be deleted instead (e.g. because it consists of only the link) — there's no point in wasting any effort on a post that's to be deleted.